# How can you prove that $B(x,r)\subseteq B(0,s)$ where $0<r<s$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, set-theory

I'm approaching the problem in the following way:
If $B(x,r)=\{y\in X:|x-y|<r\}$ and $B(0,s)=\{y\in X:|y|<s\}$ then it must be the case that $y\in (x-r,x+r)$ for the first ball and $y\in (-s,s)$ for the second. If I prove that it follows from $y\in (x-r,x+r)$ that $y\in (-s,s)$ then the first ball is in the second. If $x-r>-s$, and $x+r<s$ the statement should hold. For the first one $x<r-s$ and for the second $x<s-r$ since $s-r$ can be me made as large as we want, and since it is positive then $\exists x$ such that $(x-r,x+r)\subseteq (-s,s)$. But I'm not sure about this proof so I'm asking you for some feedback.

Comment: The statement is wrong. As an example, $B(100, 1)$ is not a subset of $B(0, 2)$.

Comment: @Martin R your statement is actually correct in my opinion but the question is asked in the textbook "Topology of metric spaces" ex. 1.2.6, 
"Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $x \in X$ and $0 < r < s$. Show that $B(x, r) \subseteq B(0, s)$. Show that they may be equal even if $r<s$".

Comment: It merely says "Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space", but then later $0$ is an element of $X$?

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo, and it should be $B(x, r) \subseteq B(x, s)$?

Comment: Are $r$ and $s$ fixed beforehand? Or are you allowed to choose $s$ freely?

Comment: I think that it is a typo. Because the next question says show that $B(x,r) \subseteq B[x,r]$. I assume that if you can change s freely then my proof essentially claims that if $x<s-r$ and it is always the case that $r<s$ then s can be changed in a way to obtain all possible $x$